# Font class reference in java

Tags: java, reference

I'd like to ask something very fundamental:

While I was writing this code:

```
font = new Font("Calibri", Font.ITALIC, 10);
gr.setFont(font);
gr.drawString("mpla mpla",x,y);
font = new Font("Sherif", Font.BOLD, 16);
gr.drawString("mpla mpla part 2",x,y);
```

I realised that my font wouldn't change in the second drawstring and in order
to work I had to put another `gr.setFont(font);` before it.

Why is this happening? I mean, I've got a reference for a `Font` object, and that is set for use on my Graphics context. When I re-assign a new object to my font reference it should normally work when `Graphics` tries to use it for the second time! but this is not the case..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have a misconception of what you're doing.

At this line:

```
font = new Font("Calibri", Font.ITALIC, 10);
```

You assign a reference to a newly created `Font` object to the variable `font`.

Then, using `gr.setFont(font);` you pass that reference to the `gr.setFont()` method. You pass **only** the reference, i.e. the "position" of that `Font` object. You don't tell `gr.setFont()` anything about the variable `font`, you only tell it the value stored in there.

In the second-to-last line `font = ...` you assign the reference to yet another new `Font` object to the variable `font`. Since the `Graphics` object has no knowledge of the `font` variable itself, it is (of course) not influenced by that change at all!

You could think of it that way:

- I write a number on a piece of paper (let's say the number is 3)
- I show you that piece of paper and ask you to remember the number
- I erase the number on the paper and write 5 on it
- I ask you which number you remembered

Comment: You seem to talk sense but to be honest I am still confused...Here's the deal; As you said, the font reference just stores the address of a new Font object. Now, if I a pass font to graphics, then when graphics are called, they will look on say location number 300 and find the "Calibri" Font object. Now, if I reassign the font reference to say location 400 ("Sherif" Font object) then when graphics try to draw on screen again, they will still check what's in font reference and will now find out about location 400! UNLESS each time we call "set" method, they create some sort of local copy...

Comment: No, as I said: you don't tell them about the `font` reference. You only tell them "look at location 300" (where 300 is the location referenced by `font`). When you reassign the new `Font` object to `font` (let's say at location 400), you change `font`, but you don't retroactively change what you passed to the `Graphics` object.

Comment: You might be confused because in C "reference" and "pointer" are two distinct things with quite different things. In Java there is no such distinction and they are usually called "references", even 'though they behave more like pointers in C (except that there's no pointer arithmetic).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right if gr will use the font which was passed in first call, at least it should (Ideally Class of gr should have defensively copied the font object and not used the same object what you used to set), in other case if implementation has not done that then whenever you change 'font' reference that you passed in setFont will change the font will change.

So if it works without use of second 'setFont()' call implementation of Graphic class has not done defensive copy. As far as 'what is happening' is concerned, it all depends whether Graphic class directly use this 'font' reference to store or it creates a copy and then store.

Comment: [`Font`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) is immutable (not a single setter, only `derive()` functions that return a new `Font), so a defensive copy is not necessary!